# Can "for most of 2020 shares in GameStop" be the subject of sentence？

Tags: grammar

> **FOR MOST of 2020 shares in GameStop, a struggling seller of video games with more than 4,000 shops across America, fetched a few dollars apiece**. The stock languished as the pandemic shuttered malls. But in August Ryan Cohen, the former boss of Chewy, an online pet-food store, started amassing a large stake. In November he wrote an animated letter to the board, urging them to review GameStop's business and invest in e-commerce to boost online sales. Investors seemed to like his plan: by January 11th, when he took a seat on GameStop’s board, his 12.7% stake had doubled in value. The shares were worth around $20.

Can "for most of 2020 shares in GameStop" be the subject of sentence？ Or should I read it as"for most of 2020,  shares in GameStop fetched a few dollars apiece"?

article link ：https://www.economist.com/graphic-detail/2021/01/27/day-traders-have-sent-gamestops-share-price-sky-high

Comment: Yes, you should read it with a comma. The PP "for most of 2020" is thus a temporal adjunct in clause structure. The subject of the sentence is the NP "shares in GameStop". The predicate is "fetched a few dollars apiece", and the NP "a struggling seller of video games with more than 4,000 shops across America" is a supplement, a loosely attached expression presenting supplementary, non-integrated content.

Comment: thank you very much